# Change width of an element in an usercontrol to the width of an element in another usercontrol using storyboard

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, binding, storyboard

I want to set the width of the "GridMenu" in my Usercontrol1 to the ActualWidth of the Grid.Column (0) in the MainWindow.

Usercontrol 1:

```
    <Usercontrol...> 
<Usercontrol.Resources>          
     <Storyboard x:Key="OpenMenu">
                <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(FrameworkElement.Width)" Storyboard.TargetName="GridMenu">
                    <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="30"/>
                    <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.5" Value="thisValueIWantToBind"/>
                </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
    </Storyboard>
</Usercontrol.Resources> 

         <Grid x:Name="GridMenu" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="30" Background="LightBlue"/>
    </Usercontrol>
```

MainWindow:

```
 <Grid Grid.Row="1" Background="Beige">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="5"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="3*"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

            <local:usercontrol1 Grid.Column="0"/>
</Grid>
```

Answer (score -1):

You can write the storyboard in code behind so that you have easy access to MainWindow from the usercontrol. Just a guess.

Comment: I thought about that, but i would like to do it in XAML.

Answer (score -1):

You can create a dependency property in usercontrol1 say e.g., Column1Width.
In the MainWindow, give some name to the first column.
               
Also,

Then in usercontrol1,